# How do I insert layout into Android menu item row?

Tags: android

How do I insert a layout into an Android menu item row?

I don't know how to create a layout like this.

Here's what I want:
[image]

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial on Android layouts.

Comment: thank you, can you give me a specific link?

Comment: http://developer.android.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" 
        android:padding="5dp">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Play with the Switch" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switchStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mySwitch"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity, implement the following code:

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_filter_layout, null);

    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            //TODO do sth here on dismiss
        }
    });

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(v); 
}
```